# Ruby On Rails :- WHM VPS server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vps, whm

I am new in Ruby on Rails. I successfully upload and run very well my ROR project on Web Host Manager- VPSserver. When I try to upload small size of video like 7 MB is successfully upload. And on my local host here I can upload 200 MB video successfully but I facing problem on WHM VPS server and When I try to upload 30 MB video file browser given me below error:

> The connection was reset The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments. If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection. If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

I change the configuration of WHM VPS (PHP Configuration Editor).

> magic_quotes_gpc = Off; register_globals = Off; default_charset = UTF-8; memory_limit = 500M; max_execution_time = 30000; upload_max_filesize = 999M; safe_mode = Off; mysql.connect_timeout = 20; session.use_cookies = On; session.use_trans_sid = Off; session.gc_maxlifetime = 12000000; allow_url_fopen = on;

But I did not get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

That definitely sounds like you're hitting a limit somewhere in your php configuration. You should be able to identify which limit you're hitting in the apache error log.

With root access, you can check it on the command line ( /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log ). If you only have access to cPanel, you can view the most recent errors on the Errors page in cPanel.